# Modify html button

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button with an online ordering system and I pasted it on my wix website.
When you click the button, it opens the ordering app, It works fine but I dont' want to see the button but only the menu, can anyone help?

```
        <!-- If you would like to customize the button, remove or change the "class" attribute inside the <span> tag --> 
    <span class="glf-button" id="glf-restaurant-order-online">See MENU & Order</span> 
    <script> 
(function(w,d,s,id,h,bid,cuid) 
{ 
var js,
fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
 l=function(){
var k=d.getElementById(bid);
 glfWidget(h,[bid],cuid), 
k&&k.removeAttribute('id');
}, b=function(s){s.addEventListener?s.addEventListener('load',l,false):s.attachEvent("onload", l);};
 if(!(js=d.getElementById(id))){ js=d.createElement(s);
js.id=id;
js.src=h+"widget/js/ewm.js"; 
b(js);
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs); 
}
else if(!w.glfWidget) b(js); else l(); 
}
(window,document,'script','glf-embedder-js',"https://www.foodbooking.com/","glf-restaurant-order-online","3bf7a72b-1ab0-412d-ac1d-cd43ee60dea5")); 
</script>
```

**[The link to the order online on my website](http://www.gooodpizza.com/#!order/c66t)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to hide your button:

```
document.getElementById("glf-restaurant-order-online").style.display="none";
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("glf-restaurant-order-online").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: Thanks this hides the button but I can't see the menu. Is there an auto run functions of the button or something similar? The way I would like it to work is that people click on order in the menu bar and the menu comes out.. Thanks